# Save memory data from function pointers c++

Tags: c++, pointers

I do have a function and I need it to be of `void` type and to pass and get back its pointers:

```
void cracking::decompose(char input[][100], int size_S, double* &Atm, int* &ID, int &size_out);
{
vector<double> AtmD;
vector<int> XsD;
...


    Atm = &AtmD[0];
    ID = &XsD[0];
    size_out = size(AtmD);

}
```

My Idea here is to get the address of the first value of the Vectors and with its size I may be able to get all the values, however when I call it in the main function it builds but the data in this memory adress is deleted and I get only garbage. Is there a way that I Maintain the data associated to these pointers?

here is how the function is called in the main:

```
int main()
{
    char oi[900][100] = { "1  0.5 C", "2  0.55 N", "3  .5  S" };
    double* xAtm = NULL;
    int* xXs = NULL;
    int tamanho;
    cracking calc;


    calc.decompose(oi, 3, xAtm, xXs, tamanho);



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are trying to use memory that is freed at the end of the method.. this is undefined

Comment: Can you please explain what you are attempting to do. This code makes no sense. Firstly, your vectors are declared locally to your `decompose` function, so once that function ends, they will be destructed. Secondly, you can't expect to assign a raw pointer to the address of the first vector element and expect that to be iterable.

Comment: standard algorithms manage their own memory, if you want to fill the vector in the method and the method is not allowed to return something (why??) then you should create the vectors outside and pass references to them to the method

Comment: I cannot pass the vectors it must be use only int, double, arrays or pointers

Comment: Look up the keyword `static`.  By prefixing your arrays or variables in the function with `static`, they will live past the end of the function execution and you'll be able to return their addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local variables will disappear after execution leaves the function.  You can't return their address because deleted objects don't have an address.

The compiler may use *registers* for the local variables.  Registers don't have useful addresses.

If you want to return the address of a variable, declare it as static:

```
double * some_function(void)
{
  static double pi = 3.14159264;
  return &pi;
}
```

Another alternative is to declare the variable in dynamic memory and return the pointer:

```
double * another_function()
{
   double * p_pi = new double(3.14159264);
   return p_pi;
}
```

Comment: If it turns into a .dll and I call this function from a software, would the static still be valid? Could it generate problems in memory?

Comment: Yes, the compiler does not emit destruction instructions for variables that are tagged as `static`.  The variable may be placed into a separate data segment along with global and automatic storage variables.  **Remember** to initialize the variable as necessary, because the assignment at declaration may not occur when you need it (depending on when DLL memory is initialized).

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand your question, but i'm not entirely sure. I am assuming you are asking about returning the pointers to a few local variables inside of another function. I think something that you need to understand here is how the stack works. When you call your decompose function, you create a new frame on the stack, with a return address to main. All the local variables will be pushed onto the stack. Once the decompose function returns, that stack space is free to be reused again.

> Is there a way that I Maintain the data associated to these pointers?

Yes! Allocate your variables on the heap. Look up `new` in C++. Hope this helps point you in the right direction!

Comment: Be aware that variables may be stored in registers and a register won't have a usable address.

Comment: Also, there is no requirement for an implementation to use stacks or heap.